# how to get Operating System install patch details with version

Tags: c#

## Operating system patch

i want  to get list of install patch of my operation system with version details in dot net,

i am trying using wmi

```
string Software = null;
string SoftwareKey = @"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall";

Software += "\r\nWINDOWS X64 Software\r\n\r\n\r\n ";
using (RegistryKey rk = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(SoftwareKey))
{
    if (rk == null)
    {
        return Software;
    }
    foreach (string skName in rk.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (RegistryKey sk = rk.OpenSubKey(skName))
        {
            try
            {
                if (!(sk.GetValue("DisplayName") == null))
                {
                    if (sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") == null)
                        Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - Install path not known \r\n ";
                    else
                        Software += sk.GetValue("DisplayName") + " - " + sk.GetValue("InstallLocation") + "\r\n ";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
return Software;
```

Comment: Please describe the issue and current behavior

Comment: i am unable to find the list of install operating system  patch detail , i  do not  have any idea how can i get it

Comment: You say that you use WMI, but your code doesn’t show that as you directly access the registry. Never do `catch (Exception ex) { }` as this will swallow all exceptions and you will never know what goes wrong and this can lead to unstable application behavior – either handle only specific exception you don’t care about or at least log errors.